# How can I query for a subdocument full of objects in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have a document with an unknown number of objects in it, each with 2 properties. It's a collection of friend lists, and I'm trying to confirm if someone has a friend with a certain username before I allow a user to send a request. I'm keeping the list of friends in a subdocument, like this:

```
>>all the _id and other properties<<, "ownerFriends":[{"friendId":"an id goes here", "friendUsername": "username"}, {"friendId":"another id", "friendUsername":"username2"}]
```

I'm trying to do a query that will return username2 if given that as input, but I don't know how to do that with dot notation because I think you need to know the specific property to look for, and these are heterodox amounts of friend objects in the ownerFriends property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the `ownerFriend` object that has `username` as the `friendUserName` you can use the following selector (assuming your collection is called Friends):

```
Friends.find({
    "ownerFriends.friendUsername": "username2"
}, {
    fields: { "ownerFriends.$": 1}
});
```

You can find a detailed explanation of how to query an array of objects based on a property here:

http://www.curtismlarson.com/blog/2015/08/08/meteor-mongodb-array-property-selector/

Answer (score 0):

In summary you have an object that contains keys, one of whose values is an array of objects. You can perform queries on the arrays using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) In your case:

```
MyCollection.find({ ownerFriends: { $elemMatch: { friendUsername: searchString }}});
```

Although I think you'll need to also query on the current user's _id. Not knowing the details of your collection, I can only speculate with:

```
MyCollection.find({ userId: Meteor.userId(), ownerFriends: { $elemMatch: { friendUsername: searchString }}});
```

Comment: When I try to do your second command (You were right about how I have it set up) it just returns the document that matches the userId without looking to see if the friendUsername is in the ownerFriends. When I did it on its own it was working properly, though (But yes I do need it to also query on the userId)

Comment: Might need an `$and`: `MyCollection.find({ $and: [ { userId: Meteor.userId() }, { ownerFriends: { $elemMatch: { friendUsername: searchString }}}]});`

Comment: I just tried it on a similar collection. If I searched using my original answer syntax then if the string I used wasn't in the array I got no results. The `$and` shouldn't be necessary.